# Existence of the 'matrix' associated to a form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $X$ be a finite set and $C(X)$ the set of functions $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
The bilinear map $Q:C(X)\times C(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a *form*.
The claim I want to prove is, that there exists a unique $l:X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$Q(f,g)=\sum\limits_{x,y \in X}l(x,y)f(x)g(y)$$

Uniqueness follows since $1_{x},1_{y} \in C(X)$ where $1_{x}$ denotes the function which takes the value $1$ for x and $0$ elsewhere. Thus for arbitrary $x,y \in X$
$$Q(1_{x},1_{y})=\sum\limits_{u,v \in X}l(u,v)1_{x}(u)1_{y}(v)=l(x,y)=l^{'}(x,y)=\sum\limits_{u,v \in X}l'(u,v)1_{x}(u)1_{y}(v)$$ Since $l(x,y)=l^{'}(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$ it follows that $l=l^{'}$.

My first thought for the proof of the existence of $l$ was to define $l(x,y):=Q(1_{x},1_{y})$ and use $f(x)=\sum\limits_{u \in X}f(u)1_{x}(u)$ together with the bilinearity of $Q$.
But this only yields
$$\sum\limits_{x,y \in X}l(x,y)f(x)g(y)=\sum\limits_{x,y \in X}Q(1_{x},1_{y})f(x)g(y)=
Q\left(\sum\limits_{x \in X}f(x)1_{x},\sum\limits_{y \in X}g(y)1_{y}\right)$$

Any suggestions how I could prove the existence? Is my idea correct and I'm only making a mistake in the calculation or do I need a different approach?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381196/matrix-representation-of-a-bilinear-form

Comment: If $X$ has $n$ elements, your $C(X)$ "is" $\mathbb R^n$. For any bilinear map $Q:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R,$ [there exists a unique matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#Coordinate_representation) $l\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $Q(u,v)=\sum l_{i,j}u_iv_j.$

Comment: I know that the result is true from my linear algebra class where we proved this by showing that the bilinear maps over a finite set (with dim n) are isomorphic to the  $n\times n$ matrices. I thought it would be possible to give a direct proof.